# Kivy .kv file passing argument

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

OK so what I want to do is have a FloorWidget with a option to add rooms dynamically with a press of a button while the app is running. I want to load specific graphic based on the room number and I don't know how to achive that in .kv file

```
<RoomWidget>:
    id: room_widget
    room_num: # would be great if you could pass this as an argument
    Image:
        source: os.path.join(GRAPHICS_DIR_PATH, "room" + str(room_widget.room_num))
```

Is there a way to do this? Could I somehow initilize room_num in python file by passing it into the RoomWidget constructor and access it in .kv file?

```
class RoomWidget(Screen, Widget):
    def __init__(self, room_num, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.room_num = room_num

<RoomWidget>:
    size_hint: (.2, .35)
    source: os.path.join(GRAPHICS_DIR_PATH, "room" + str(self.room_num))
    Image:
        source: source
```

If I do sth like this I get an error: AttributeError: 'RoomWidget' object has no attribute 'room_num'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by making a `property` of `RoomWidget` Like this:

```
class RoomWidget(Screen):
    room_num = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, room_num, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.room_num = room_num
```

Then, in your 'kv':

```
#:import os os
#:set GRAPHICS_DIR_PATH '.'
<RoomWidget>:
    size_hint: (.2, .35)
    source: os.path.join(GRAPHICS_DIR_PATH, "room" + str(self.room_num) + '.png')
    Image:
        source: root.source
```

Note that you do not need to extend both `Screen` and `Widget`, because `Screen` is a `Widget`.